# How to open disabled fields in Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I'm trying to fill a form using Selenium, but the form has a disabled field.

Disabled field

[image: Disabled field]

The field is only editable when I modify the field above it.

Open field

[image: Open field]

When I set the value directly using the code below, the field is not open for editing

```
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('field_id').value='" + brand + "'");
```

Example

[image: Example of not editable field]

I tried to simulate the click in the field, press the tab key, press the enter key, but none had any effect.

Is there any way for me to trigger the same event that the user is performing on the screen to release the field through selenium or javascript?

In the HTML code, the options are not listed, so the options are loaded from a javascript function that is executed after filling the first field

Options

[image: Options]

Comment: Your field is disabled. If you would open it up in your browser you would still not be able to click it to select anything. It's disabled. You need to enable it first to make it interactable.

Comment: This is the question, when I select the first dropdown option on the screen, it enables the field for editing, but when I select the first dropdown value using Selenium or javascript, it does not enable the field

Comment: aahhh, now I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I really liked it I'll copy Tschallackas Intro:

> Your test is flawed. You are not following user behaviour.

Sadly I totally disagree with the rest of the answer :(

I would like to ask *WHY* are you trying to use JavaScript?
Is this something a real User would do? I really doubt it!

The crucial thing with End2End-Tests is to simulate your User behaviour as close as possible. Therefore I would suggest to use the Webdriver to do things like that in your Seleniumtest.

```
Select dropdown = new Select(webdriver.findElement(By.id("field_id")));
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("ONESOURCE");
```

(Assuming you are using Java by the tag on your question)

Answer (score 0):

Your test is flawed. You are not following user behaviour.

You are doing:

```
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('field_id').value='" + brand + "'");
```

Which tries to change a value on a dropdown. This doesn't work because dropdowns work via a selectedIndex, which you can use to get the correct value from the options collection on the dropdown element.
Also, when a user changes a value, a change event is triggered, which notifies other scripts that listen to that event that something has changed. You need to emulate this too to trigger your change script.

```js
js.executeScript("let select = document.getElementById('field_id');"+
                 "select.selectedIndex = 1;/* change this to the value corresponding to the correct index of the value you wish to test. */"+
                 "select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));");
```

See the example below for how the javascript should work.

```js
document.getElementById('field_id').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
   if(e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value > 1) {
      document.getElementById('the_disabled').disabled = false;
   }
   else {
      document.getElementById('the_disabled').disabled = true;
   }
});
document.getElementById('trigger').addEventListener('click',() => {
   let select = document.getElementById('field_id');
   select.selectedIndex = 1;// change this to the value corresponding to the correct index of the value you wish to test.
   select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
});
```

```html
<select id="field_id">
 <option value="1">--none--</option>
 <option value="2">COMPANY A</option>
 <option value="3">COMPANY B</option>
</select>
<BR/>
<select id="the_disabled" disabled="disabled">
 <option value="0">--none--</option>
 <option value="1">SELECT A</option>
 <option value="2">Select B</option>
</select>
<BR/>
<button id="trigger">Trigger selenium emulation</button>
```